# Image recognition search software?

Tags: software-recommendation, search, photo-management

I have recently lost an image. I know it is somewhere on my machine, but I don't know where. I have an image which looks very similar to it. Is there any kind software for Ubuntu similar to the Google search facility which allows you to search for images similar to, or exactly the same as other images? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`findimagedupes` is a common command-line application for finding similar or identical images. You can install it by executing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install findimagedupes
```

You could also set up an OpenCV script using Python, but that would take a bit of studying.